Why do some meme token addresses end in the word "pump"?
I only noticed this recently. A long address and the end is "pump". But only some of them. Does this have any meaning?

Tokens ending in ...pump are created by pump.fun
These token addresses are pre-grinded and assigned when a token is created on the platform.
You can bypass this if you use the Pump API https://pumpportal.fun/
If you want to grind yourself, you can use the Solana CLI command
solana-keygen grind --ends-with pump:1

This will try to find for you a token address ending with pump
You can also use Solana Web3.js but it is not recommended.
